# Logs with arbitrary numbers of entries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm designing a db in PostgreSQL that primarily stores info about different people. I'd like to associate a log with each person, consisting of the date and a text entry. Logs can have arbitrary numbers of entries. Here's the ideas I've toyed with:

1. What I think I want is a `log_table` like this:

   ```
   person_id | row_num | row_date | row_text
   -----------------------------------------
           1 |       1 | 01/01/12 | Blah...
           2 |       1 | 01/02/12 | Foo...
           1 |       2 | 01/04/12 | Bar...
   ```

But I don't know how to get `row_num` to increment properly; it should default to one more than the largest current `row_num` for that person_id. In other words, the `row_num`s for a given `person_id` should be sequential.

1. Or I can just have `row_num` increment regardless of `person_id` so that every log entry has a distinct row number. But it doesn't seem very satisfying to have `person_id` 1's log jump from row 1 to row 3, and this could also make errors hard to spot.
2. My last idea is to include the log directly in the `person` table, by making a composite type `log_entry = (date, text)`. Then a column `log` in the `person` table can store an array:

   ```
   person_id | name | log
   ----------------------
           1 | Bob  | {(01/01/12, Blah...), (01/04/12, Bar...)}
   ```

But this seems cumbersome.

So my questions are, a) which solution if any is good design; b) any way to solve the auto-incrementing problem for solution 1? If it matters, this is a small db for personal use; I want good structure but it's highly likely I'll be the only user. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a timestamp to store the time when the row has been inserted?

That way you don't need the extra row_num column in the table, and you can always "calculate" it on the fly:

```
SELECT person_id,
       row_number() over (partition by person_id order by row_timestamp) as row_num,
       row_timestamp,
       row_text
FROM log_table
```

Of course if there are chances that a user generates more than one entry per *micro* second that you might wind up with log entries with exactly the same timestamp.

But even in a busy system this is quite unlikely (but not impossible).

If you can't (or don't want to to) use a timestamp, you can always use a sequence that increments for all users and then use the row_number() function to generate a gapless row number during retrieval (as shown above, just use an order by on the column populated by the sequence).

Comment: Thanks! The row_number() function is exactly what I needed (and didn't know about). I don't want to use a timestamp because the entries are made manually and I can't guarantee they'll be added in chronological order, but the basic idea is perfect.